# Vue 2.0 scss syntax with webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-2

I'm trying to get 
`<style lang="scss">` (not "sass") to work in .vue files, so that Atom can highlight properly. The solutions I've found seems to apply to a different version of either vue or webpack. I've got vue 2.1.8 and webpack 2.1.0-beta.22

This doesn't work:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
//test

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './../dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            'scss': 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
            // 'sass': 'vue-style!css!sass?indentedSyntax'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file',
        query: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    proxy: {
      '/site/api/**': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8888',
        secure: false,
        "changeOrigin": true
      },
      '/site/font/*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8888',
        secure: false,
        "changeOrigin": true
      }
    }
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  ])
}
```

I've also tried
`vue: {}` syntax, which i think is for vue 1  and `resolve: {}` instead of `module: {}`, I think that's for webpack 1, but I'm not sure.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By accident i found out that this has already been solved in a newer version of vue. So I:

- made a new vue install
- checked the versions of webpack and webpack-dev-server
- installed those versions
- copied over the webpack.config.js

Answer (score 3):

This worked in the end (copied from newer vue install)

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './../dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this nessessary.
            'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    proxy: {
      '/site/api/**': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8888',
        secure: false,
        "changeOrigin": true
      },
      '/site/font/*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8888',
        secure: false,
        "changeOrigin": true
      }
    }
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, installing `node-sass` and `sass-loader` was enough to make it work with the vue-cli webpack setup for both vue 1 and vue 2. One of those had to be installed globally if I remember correctly.